# Emacs: Creating directory: permission denied

Tags: emacs

I'm using emacs on a Linux box where I have no home directory. When using emacs I will sometimes get the warning:

```
Creating directory: permission denied, /home/username
```

I don't know what it is trying to access in the home directory. I've set make-backup-files to nil.

My question is:

- What is emacs trying to do in my home directory?
- Can I make it stop doing this so I can use emacs without hitting this non-existent directory?
- Or alternatively, can I point this to some other directory?

Comment: If you `strace -o /tmp/emacs.out emacs` you can catch the system calls that `emacs` is making that try to reference your home directory. It might be a good start to finding out what configuration item needs to change.

Comment: Why no home directory? Every account on a unix box should have a home directory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, didn't think of the very low-tech solution:

```
$ HOME=/tmp emacs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and then you should get a backtrace the next time the error occurs (if it's an error).

Answer (score 0):

Are you editing a file in your home directory? Maybe it's trying to create the auto backup copy?